# Why doesn't instanceof work on instances of Error subclasses under babel-node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am seeing that the `instanceof` operator doesn't work on instances of `Error` subclasses, when running under [babel-node](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node) version 6.1.18/Node version 5.1.0 on OS X. Why is this? The same code works well in the browser, try my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rvmmv9g0/) for an example.

The following code outputs `true` in the browser, whereas under babel-node it's false:

```
class Sub extends Error {
}

let s = new Sub()
console.log(`The variable 's' is an instance of Sub: ${s instanceof Sub}`)
```

I can only imagine this being due to a bug in babel-node, since `instanceof` works for other base classes than `Error`.

### .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

### Compiled Output

This is the JavaScript compiled by babel 6.1.18:

```
'use strict';

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

var Sub = (function (_Error) {
  _inherits(Sub, _Error);

  function Sub() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Sub);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, Object.getPrototypeOf(Sub).apply(this, arguments));
  }

  return Sub;
})(Error);

var s = new Sub();
console.log('The variable \'s\' is an instance of Sub: ' + (s instanceof Sub));
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I tested both with online babel repl and using babel-node (latest).

Comment: What preset are you using with Babel? Maybe posting the transpiled script would help reproduce the issue

Comment: @DenysSéguret Thanks, going to check further.

Comment: @RGraham The fiddle uses Babel in the browser? The point is that Babel works differently in the browser vs Node apparently.

Comment: @RGraham I've posted the compiled script.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

tl;dr If you're on Babel 6, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend

Extending builtin types like `Array` and `Error` and such has never been supported in Babel. It is perfectly valid in a real ES6 environment, but there are requirements to make it work that are very difficult to transpile in a way that is compatible with older browsers. It "worked" in Babel 5 in that it didn't throw an error, but objects instantiated from the extended subclass did not work like they were supposed to, for example:

```
class MyError extends Error {}

var e1 = new MyError();
var e2 = new Error();

console.log('e1', 'stack' in e1);
console.log('e2', 'stack' in e2);
```

results in

```
e1 false
e2 true
```

While it did not error out, the subclass does not properly get a 'stack' like errors are supposed to. Similarly, if you were to extend `Array` it might behave somewhat like an array, and have array methods, but it did not behave fully like an array.

The Babel 5 documentation specifically called this out as an edge-case of classes to be aware of.

In Babel 6, classes were changed to be more spec-compliant in how subclassing is handled, and a side-effect of that is that now the above code will *still* not work, but it will not work in a different way than before. This has been covered in https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T3083, but I'll elaborate here on a potential solution.

To return Babel 5 subclassing behavior (which remember, is still not right or recommended), you can wrap the builtin constructor in your own temporary class, e.g.

```
function ExtendableBuiltin(cls){
    function ExtendableBuiltin(){
        cls.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    ExtendableBuiltin.prototype = Object.create(cls.prototype);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(ExtendableBuiltin, cls);

    return ExtendableBuiltin;
}
```

With this helper, rather than doing

```
class MyError extends Error {}
```

do

```
class MyError extends ExtendableBuiltin(Error) {}
```

In your specific case however, you have said that you are on Node 5.x. Node 5 has support for native ES6 classes without transpiling. I'd recommend you use those by dropping the `es2015` preset and instead using [`node5`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-node5) so you get native classes, among other things. In that context,

```
class MyError extends Error {}
```

will work the way you expect.

For people not on Node 4/5, or recent Chrome only, you may want to consider using something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/error. You can also explore https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend. The `approximate` option from that is the same behavior from Babel 5. Beware that the non-`approximate` behavior is definitely edge-casey and may not work in 100% of cases.

Comment: Aha thanks. So what is the recommended way of creating new exception classes then??

Comment: After all, the MDN [recommends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) prototypal inheritance of `Error` to create new exception classes. AFAICT, this should correspond to subclassing in ES6, unless I'm overlooking something. I also found [this article](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html) on ES6 class semantics that has an example exactly of sublassing `Error`.

Comment: I expanded my answer a bit. Subclassing in ES6 is much more complicated than you would expect and does not map nicely into ES5.

Comment: Aha, now it's clearer that it's in fact an artifact of transpiling. Thanks.

Comment: I can't install `babel-preset-node5`: `Error extracting /Users/arve/.npm/babel-preset-node5/6.1.4/package.tgz archive: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/arve/.npm/babel-preset-node5/6.1.4/package.tgz'`.

Comment: It's community maintained so I'm not sure. Maybe worth trying `babel-preset-es2015-node5` instead? That one looks a little more solid anyway.

Comment: Looks like the issue with `babel-preset-node5` has been fixed.

Comment: Is it fixed yet? Or will it ever be fixed? They put `Wontfix` tag on this issue in phabricator, this is kind of disappointing because I thought I should expect this feature to work, at least if Babel did it right and according to the specification.

Comment: BTW saying that subclassing bult-ins in ES2015 is _not recommended_ is not true. Actually it is recommended and was explicitly discussed on the ES mailing list many times…

Comment: Extending builtins is a brand new feature in ES6 specifically because native class syntax allows for greater control over the process of object creation. If you are transpiling your classes, it means you don't get that, which makes properly transpiling buildin-subclassing impossible. The best you can do is a rough approximation either manually or with the Babel plugin I linked to. That is why it's a Wontfix.

Comment: For these use cases I've just been writing them in ES5 e.g. `var CustomError = function(message){
  Error.call(this, message)
  this.message = message 
}`

Comment: For anyone using babel-preset-env, note that simply setting the "targets" to include only node (at a sufficiently advanced version) prevents classes from being transpiled, and solves this problem.

Comment: I've hit this error again when upgrading to node 20. Transpilation may be an issue here, but it's hard to know. I'm not using babel, only swc.

Answer (score 8):

`instanceof` will not work for subclassed errors if the compile target is set to "es5". I set the target to "es6" in my `tsconfig.json` and `instanceof` produced the right result.