# babeljs doesn't transpile extended classes properly

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I've got this example code from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends) (slightly modified to print out results):

```js
"use strict";

class myDate extends Date {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  getFormattedDate() {
    var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    return this.getDate() + "-" + months[this.getMonth()] + "-" + this.getFullYear();
  }
}

var testDate = new myDate();
document.write(testDate.getFormattedDate());
```

It works on Google Chrome browser and node5, but when I transpile it using babeljs to ES5 (ES2015 preset) it doesn't work:

```js
"use strict";

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

var myDate = function (_Date) {
  _inherits(myDate, _Date);

  function myDate() {
    _classCallCheck(this, myDate);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, Object.getPrototypeOf(myDate).call(this));
  }

  _createClass(myDate, [{
    key: 'getFormattedDate',
    value: function getFormattedDate() {
      var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
      return this.getDate() + "-" + months[this.getMonth()] + "-" + this.getFullYear();
    }
  }]);

  return myDate;
}(Date);

var testDate = new myDate();
document.write(testDate.getFormattedDate());
```

Why?

I found the answer in [babel docs](http://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#subclassable-built-ins):

> Partial support 
>   Built-in subclassability should be evaluated on a case-by-case basis as classes such as HTMLElement can be subclassed while many such as Date, Array and Error cannot be due to ES5 engine limitations.

I'd appreciate if babel throw an error upon seeing native objects extensions (which it doesn't support) instead of pretending all is rosy and producing faulty code :/

Comment: You may also be interested in the approach mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870684/why-doesnt-instanceof-work-on-instances-of-error-subclasses-under-babel-node/33877501#33877501

Answer (score 2):

According to [ECMAScript 6 compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), BabelJS doesn't support class extends.