# Node/Babel - extended class missing methods

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a class like the following:

```
export default class Wave extends Array {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.direction = "";
    }

    setDirection(direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    getDirection() {
        return this.direction;
    }
}
```

when i try to do the following

```
import Wave from 'app/Classes/Wave';
var wave = new Wave();

ohlcs.forEach(function (ohlc) {
    wave.push(ohlc);
});
wave.setDirection("up");
```

I get this error:

```
wave.setDirection is not a function
```

The same code was working in nodejs 5.10 with the classic module.exports:
`module.exports = class Wave extends Array`

Can someone explain me what is happening?

Comment: Can you show me how you import the class Wave?

Comment: I edited the code to show it

Comment: The code that you provided works as expected for me, anyways, why you want to extend from Array?

Comment: I think this is probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870684/why-doesnt-instanceof-work-on-instances-of-error-subclasses-under-babel-node
can anyone confirm?

Comment: What are you using to transform your code from ES6?

Comment: babel-cli 6.7.7, babel-presets-es2015 6.6.0

Comment: @Cuz yes, looks like a duplicate

Comment: @Bergi the fact is that the title for that question is so specific that it's hard to find it by search

Comment: @Cuz: Now it's easier to find :-)