# instanceof using ES6 class Inheritance chain doesn't work

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Using ES6 `class` syntax, I'm wondering why the `instanceof` operator doesn't work for the inheritance chain when there are more than one chain of inheritance?

> *(optional read)*
>
> > #### How `instanceof` operator works?
> >
> > In `obj instanceof Constructor`, the `instanceof` operator checks if the `'prototype'` property of the `Constructor` function is present in the *prototype* chain of the `obj`. If it is present, return `true`. Otherwise, `false`.
>
> ---

In the following snippet, the `BTError` inherits from `Error` (***1.***) and `SomeError` extends from `BTError` (***3.***).
But as we can see from (***4.***), the `instanceof` operator results `false` for `new SomeError() instanceof BTError` which in my understanding should be `true`.

```js
class BTError extends Error {}
console.log('1.', Reflect.getPrototypeOf(BTError.prototype) === Error.prototype); // 1. true
console.log('2.', new BTError() instanceof Error); // 2. true

console.log('');

class SomeError extends BTError {}
console.log('3.', Reflect.getPrototypeOf(SomeError.prototype) === BTError.prototype); // 3. true
console.log('4.', new SomeError() instanceof BTError); // 4. false

console.log('');

class SpecificError extends SomeError {}
console.log('5.', Reflect.getPrototypeOf(SpecificError.prototype) === SomeError.prototype); // 5. true
console.log('6.', new SpecificError() instanceof Error); // 6. true
console.log('7.', new SpecificError() instanceof BTError); // 7. false
console.log('8.', new SpecificError() instanceof SomeError); // 8. false
```

---

### Question

Is there anything non-trivial which I'm unable to comprehend or is `instanceof` operator just acting *weird*?

Comment: I get 8x `true` in FF, Edge and Chrome

Comment: @Thomas true here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o93Lm0rc/321/ it prints 8 times true

Comment: Try disabling BableJs from the snippet and you'll get all checks `true`. Looks like the transpilation is screwing up ...

Comment: @alebianco thanks all. Indeed, Babel.js is the one acting *weird*.

Comment: @abhisekp i expanded my comment in a full blown answer after digging a bit around the problem

Comment: related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33877501/896465

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Focusing on the last piece of your example

You're converting this code using BabelJS to make it compatible

```js
class BTError extends Error {}
class SomeError extends BTError {}
class SpecificError extends SomeError {}

console.log('6.', new SpecificError() instanceof Error);
console.log('7.', new SpecificError() instanceof BTError);
console.log('8.', new SpecificError() instanceof SomeError);
```

This is the transpiled version of the code above

```js
'use strict';

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
    if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
        throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
    }
}

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) {
    if (!self) {
        throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called");
    }
    return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self;
}

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) {
    if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) {
        throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass);
    }
    subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, {
        constructor: {
            value: subClass,
            enumerable: false,
            writable: true,
            configurable: true
        }
    });
    if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass;
}

var BTError = function(_Error) {
    _inherits(BTError, _Error);

    function BTError() {
        _classCallCheck(this, BTError);

        return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (BTError.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(BTError)).apply(this, arguments));
    }

    return BTError;
}(Error);

var SomeError = function(_BTError) {
    _inherits(SomeError, _BTError);

    function SomeError() {
        _classCallCheck(this, SomeError);

        return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (SomeError.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(SomeError)).apply(this, arguments));
    }

    return SomeError;
}(BTError);

var SpecificError = function(_SomeError) {
    _inherits(SpecificError, _SomeError);

    function SpecificError() {
        _classCallCheck(this, SpecificError);

        return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (SpecificError.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(SpecificError)).apply(this, arguments));
    }

    return SpecificError;
}(SomeError);

console.log('6.', new SpecificError() instanceof Error); // 6. true
console.log('7.', new SpecificError() instanceof BTError); // 7. false
console.log('8.', new SpecificError() instanceof SomeError); // 8. false
```

I think the problem stems from the `_inherit` method, that assigns to `subClass.prototype` not the `superClass.prototype` directly, but an object created by merging that and another set of default properties.

With this chain of prototypes the inheritance would work but the instanceof operator would fail to travel it by reference, and so you get `false` where you expect `true`.

Apparently, according to [this bug report](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4058), it's a known and expected behaviour (ie. limitation) and a possible workaround is to use [babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend](https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend)

Answer (score 11):

Had this problem with TypeScript. Solved it by adding the following in the class constructor after the super calls:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(this, YOUR_CLASS_HERE.prototype);
```

Not sure if it helps you.

Answer (score 4):

In my case `instanceof` did not work with a compile target set to "es5". When changed to "es6" it produced the right result.