# Bluebird filtered catch with babel and extending Error class

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, bluebird

I'am running a nodejs (server) project (v6.11.2) and on that project I have defined custom errors by extending the Error class. I use babel to compile, the config for babel I use is:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

The AppError class:

```
export default class AppError extends Error {
    constructor (message, status) {
        super(message);

        this.name = this.constructor.name;

        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);

        this.status = status || 500;

    }
}
```

I want to check if the cancel method throws an AppError. When I try to use the bluebird filtered catch, I get the following error:

> Class constructor AppError cannot be invoked without 'new'

```
cancel()
    .catch(AppError, (e) => {
        // This is not working
    });
```

But the following code will just work:

```
cancel()
    .catch((e) => {
        if (e instanceof AppError) {
             // This is working
         }

        throw e;
    });
```

Can someone please explain why the bluebird approach isn't working?

I have seen this post: [Why doesn't instanceof work on instances of Error subclasses under babel-node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870684/why-doesnt-instanceof-work-on-instances-of-error-subclasses-under-babel-node/33877501#33877501) But I can't figure it out.

Comment: So did using the plugin in that other SO question you linked not work? It's definitely the same issue.

Comment: @loganfsmyth No, that did not work. Reading that post I also assume that that plugin should not be needed because "node has support for native ES6 classes"

Comment: Possibly. What's the full stacktrace of the `cannot be invoked` error you get? Generally best to always include that.

Comment: Omg found it! The cancel function is a async function. And so the returned promise is a native promise and not a bluebird promise.

Comment: Ahh, that'll do it :) You'd have to do `Bluebird.resolve(cancel()).catch(..)`